# Very Basics of Micro python, defining variables and Scope, taking user input, using a "thumby" micro console

Tags: micropython

So my partner bought me a little thing called a "thumby" for my birthday, a tiny little games console with a 72*40 pixel screen, that runs games you can write with micro python.

It comes with a tiny tutorial on how to make your first game, (https://thumby.us/Code-Editor/Get-Started/), so first off i followed the tutorial, fiddled a tiny bit with the frame rate and a different bitmap and all was fine. This first game just displays a bitmap on screen that slowly bounces up and down, very cute, but not much to it

Next i decided i would try take user input, so that the user can move the bitmap to the left or right slightly with buttons, to do this i tried to declare a global variable "xOffset" and then create a function to take user input, and if the xOffset is in a sensible range then adjust it (the code i have added is commented with !!!!! prior, everything else is the tutorial code). Then i call this handleInput function within the loop at the bottom, but i get the following error:

```
Syntax errror
Traceback most recent call
file <stdin> line 1 in <module>
file games/willy2.py in line 23
```

line 23 is the first line of my handleInput function, where i attempt to check the xOffset is within an acceptbale range.

I should probably add my experience with python at all is very limited, i have coed all sorts of games with javascript and html canvas but never anything major with python before, it may be i am trying to use js style methods with python? it could be to do with scope and how i am declaring things?

the code is below, before adding my new function the code ran perfectly (there is an emulator you can test with on the link above too)

```
import time
import thumby
import math

# BITMAP: width: 32, height: 32
bitmap0 = bytearray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,248,36,34,33,47,33,34,36,248,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,128,64,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,63,64,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
           0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,16,32,32,32,32,16,8,16,32,32,32,32,16,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
           
# Make a sprite object using bytearray (a path to binary file from 'IMPORT SPRITE' is also valid)
thumbySprite = thumby.Sprite(32, 32, bitmap0)

# Set the FPS (without this call, the default fps is 30)
thumby.display.setFPS(30)

# !!!!! Custom code, set X axis offset to take input from user
global xOffset
xOffset = 0

# !!!!! Take user button input
def handleInput()
    if thumby.buttonR.pressed() and (xOffset < 10)
        xOffset = xOffset + 1
    if thumby.buttonL.pressed() and (xOffset > -10)
        xOffset = xOffset - 1
    
    

while(1):
    t0 = time.ticks_ms()   # Get time (ms)
    thumby.display.fill(0) # Fill canvas to black
    
    # QQQQQ Custom code, handle input
    handleInput()
    
    bobRate = 250 # Set arbitrary bob rate (higher is slower)
    bobRange = 2  # How many pixels to move the sprite up/down (-5px ~ 5px)

    # Calculate number of pixels to offset sprite for bob animation
    bobOffset = math.sin(t0 / bobRate) * bobRange
    
    # Center the sprite using screen and bitmap dimensions and apply bob offset
    # !!!!! Also now applys my custom xOffset
    thumbySprite.x = int(((thumby.display.width/2) - (32/2)) + xOffset)
    thumbySprite.y = int(round((thumby.display.height/2) - (32/2) + bobOffset))
    
    # Display the bitmap using bitmap data, position, and bitmap dimensions
    thumby.display.drawSprite(thumbySprite)
    thumby.display.update()
```

I have tried adjusting the scope when declaring both xOffset and the function itself, I have tried calling the function from a different place, I have tried nesting my if statements instead in case it was a syntax issue, but to no avail.

I'm aware this is probably a very basic question and apologise for that, but i can find almost no documentation on thumby and micropython, ie how the input and stuff works, I have basically just had too look through the other games on the arcade to try and work out how to take input (on the development environment site you can click arcade and open and run any game on there, or look through the code, naturally there is a version of doom, very stripped down, but still very cool).

If anyone has any experience with thumby, micropython, or indeed any tutorials/documentation i can look at that would be blooming awesome. Sorry for taking up your time with this basic question, but hey if you didnt know thumby existed then the online development environment is kinda fun to play with anyway even if you dont have the lil console (its based on some kind of raspberry pi chip if that is relevant info, and i believe costs about 30 quid)

Comment: You're missing a `:` in the definition of `handleInput`, which should read: `def handleInput():`

Comment: ...and also in your `if` statements, for which the syntax is `if <condition>:` (so, e.g., `if thumby.buttonR.pressed() and (xOffset < 10):`).

Comment: If you haven't already, you may want to walk through the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). While micropython and python differ in some areas, the syntax is generally the same (with the [exception of features introduced since python 3.4](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/index.html)).